# Problems with Installing Android Studio on Linux Mint

Tags: android-studio, linux-mint

I have the android-studio folder and am trying to execute ./studio.sh.

The problem appears as the following:

```
/android-studio$ ./studio.sh 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.idea.Main
```

Anyone else have this problem?

I have java installed already.

Comment: A fresh download/install could help, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

delete folder 
linux 
i delete and run and work for me  below directory

~/.config/JetBrains/

[enter link description here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html?_ga=2.268333190.905641784.1588828257-1882460653.1586174907#default-dirs)